# Load test sonar instance

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarlint

we have a sonar instance installed on a single m5 large ec2 instance. We want to load test this by running mvn sonar:sonar or any other idea if some can suggest to load test before we roll this out for enter org wide. Can someone give me ideas on how can I prove that this instance will sustain the concurrent sonar scan load when 200+ developers scan concurrently.
Also my second question is  we are debating on using sonarlint connecting to remote sonar instance Vs maven goal connecting to remote sonar instance. Which option is preferred ?

Comment: We've been running SQ on m5.xlarge, having more than 200 users and it only consumes 5-6% CPU in peak. Note also that SQ will not run concurrent analysis unless you have enterprise edition; all analyses will be scheduled and will be executed one by one (or by how many computing workers you have assigned in enterprise edition). Greater amount of scan requests will not increase the load on the server, rather it would increase delay of getting results (quality gate result).

Comment: Thanks @raspy for responding so basically if we plan to use community edition we cannot run concurrent analysis that's a bummer and good to know about that ! We also have enterprise edition procured but there is a problem with that due to 5M line of code  limitation so that means after few developers scan the limit is reached and thus we can't rely on that and we are exploring the option to increase the line limitation. Any other ideas that you can think of with out procuring or spending money to increase the SQ line limit?

Comment: Please note that line limit is not counted for every scan, but rather for every project, e.g. if you have analysis for a project that is 1M in size, even if you run 20 scans for this project it will still be counted as 1M. I would think of reducing the size by reviewing what  you need to scan (maybe you have 3rd party code that can be excluded from scan?) You can also use enterprise editions for languages that are not supported in community edition, although you will miss security hotspot scanning for those.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @raspy